# How to Prove The Complement Of The Domain Is Complement Of The Image If f Is Bijective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, theorem-provers

It seems true that $f(\overline{X}) = \overline{f(X)}$ for $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $X$ is any subset of $A$ if and only if $f$ is bijective.But I couldn't write it as a formal way like epsilon argument.It makes sense to me but the trouble I have is with the formal prove.

Comment: Of course not ! Take $f(x)=x\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]}$. Is surjective : $[0,1]\to \mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ but $f\left(\overline{[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q}\right)\neq \overline{f([0,1]\cap \mathbb Q)}$

Comment: What if it is bijective it is surely  true. Let me change the question then

Comment: Now it's not : $f(x)=x\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]}-x\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q\cap [0,1]}$. It's bijective $[0,1]\to (\mathbb Q\cap [0,1])\cup((\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q)\cap (0,-1])$ but $f(\overline{[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q})\neq \overline{f([0,1]\cap \mathbb Q)}$. What is exactely your exercise ?